# Synaptics - Multitouch tapping works, but not multitouch clicking

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

This is my first post on askUbuntu, so welcome everyone! :)

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my T440s and I find it very annoying that I cannot seem to be able to modify my synaptics configuration. I want to have the following:

Two Finger Tap and Click = right button

Three Finger Tap and Click = middle button

But the only thing which I have from default is:

Two Finger Tap = right button

Three Finger Tap = middle button

Trying to configure synclient doesn't make a difference:

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 1310
RightEdge               = 4826
TopEdge                 = 2220
BottomEdge              = 4636
FingerLow               = 25
FingerHigh              = 30
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 218
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 99
HorizScrollDelta        = 99
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0403307
TouchpadOff             = 1
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 2
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 3
ClickFinger3            = 2
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 8
VertHysteresis          = 8
ClickPad                = 1
RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3068
RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
RightButtonAreaTop      = 4326
RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)